# I don't understand how to deal with inequalities when searching for a special $m$

Tags: real-analysis

Say I want to find $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for some $u\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $(u-\frac{1}{m})^3>2$. Expanding we obtain $u^3-\frac{3u^2}{m}+\frac{3u}{m^2}-\frac{1}{m^3}>2$. Now in every example I see in my textbook they will do something like $u^3-\frac{3u^2}{m}+\frac{3u}{m^2}>u^3-\frac{3u^2}{m}+\frac{3u}{m^2}-\frac{1}{m^3}>2$ and continue simplifying until it's easy to solve for $m$.

This makes absolutely no sense to me since if we find $m$ from the larger expression it is my current opinion that this $m$ will perhaps be to small to satisfy the smaller equation.

Comment: The larger m is the more predominate $3u^2/m$ will be compared to $3u/m^2$.  So the smaller $3u^2/m$ will be so the larger $u^3 - 3u^2/m + 3u/m^2$ will be.

Comment: $u^3 - 3u^2/m + 3u/m^2 > 2 \rightarrow u^3*m^2 - 3u^2m + 3u > 2m^2 \rightarrow (u^3 - 2)m^2 - 3u^2m > 3u \rightarrow (u^3 - 2)m^2 > 3u \rightarrow m^2 > 3u/(u^3 - 2) \rightarrow m > \sqrt{3u/(u^3 - 2)}$ will be sufficiently large enough for m.  See m did not get smaller, it got bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DON'T EXPAND!  Take the 3rd root.

$(u-\frac{1}{m})^3>2$

$(u-\frac{1}{m}) > 2^{\frac 1 3}$

$ u - 2^{\frac 1 3} > \frac{1}{m}$

$ m > \frac{1}{u - 2^{\frac 1 3}}$

(assuming $m > 0$)